# php variable in string not appering

Tags: php

This is my mailer's `$header` code.

I wanted to print the value of `$em` in `from:<>` but sadly it is not working.

i don't know PHP at expert level so kindly fix this problem, also I would like to know why this is happening.

```
$em="admin@domain.com";
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:  <$em>" . "\r\n";
echo $headers;
```

**Current Output:**

---

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 From:
```

---

**Expected Output:**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 From: <admin@domain.com>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as `<>` denotes a HTML tag your browser is hiding what it thinks is the broken HTML, if you view source you will see your string.

alternatively

```
echo htmlspecialchars($headers);
```

Comment: `$flag = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` can you please look over this code my mail is not working